# htaccess to accept localhost/demo/index/

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to run index.php in my localhost, and htaccess not accepting localhost/demo/index/  . Please help me I want url like localhost/demo/index/

I have tried to run localhost/demo/index it worked

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

php_value upload_max_filesize 10M    
php_value post_max_size 10M    
php_value max_execution_time 200  
php_value max_input_time 200
```

I expect the browser should accept localhost/demo/index/

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the difference between a relative and an absolut path, your attempt would rewrite like that:

`/demo/index` => `/demo/demo/index`

This is a slightly modified version of your suggestion which will probably work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [END,QSA]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).